# Sum not returning accurate values

Tags: join, sum, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to write a query to find out how many customers I have per fixed period of time.  The periods are already set in the DB and I'm simply running a sum on the customers in that period.

Using:

```
select distinct numguests, checknum
from guest_check_hist
where revenuecenterid in ('146708') and openfixedperiod = '89'
    and openbusinessdate between dateAdd(day, -2,getDate()) and dateAdd(day, -1,getDate())`
```

I find that I had 7 orders totaling 10 customers.

I then run:

```
Select Distinct MENU_ITEM_FIXED_PERIOD_TOTAL.businessDate as 'Effective Date',
    sum(H.guests) as guests, menu_item_fixed_period_total.fixedperiod,
    menu_item_fixed_period_total.revenuecenterid
FROM MENU_ITEM_FIXED_PERIOD_TOTAL
inner JOIN (
    select distinct checknum, numguests as guests, openbusinessdate, revenuecenterid, openfixedperiod 
    from guest_check_hist
    where openbusinessdate between dateAdd(day, -2,getDate()) and dateAdd(day, -1,getDate())
) H ON Menu_item_fixed_period_total.businessdate = H.openbusinessdate and menu_item_fixed_period_total.revenuecenterid = H.revenuecenterid and H.openfixedperiod = menu_item_fixed_period_total.fixedperiod
where menu_item_fixed_period_total.revenuecenterid in ('146708')
    and menu_item_fixed_period_total.businessdate between dateAdd(day, -2,getDate()) and
    dateAdd(day, -1,getDate()) and fixedperiod = '89'
group by fixedperiod, businessdate, menu_item_fixed_period_total.revenuecenterid
order by fixedperiod`
```

and find that I had 200 guests.

Obviously this isn't right.

Numguests is of datatype Int.  Can you point me in the right direction on where my error is?

Actual Data:

Individual Orders:

- numguets  checknum
- 0, 2917
- 1,       2918
- 1,   2921
- 1,  2922
- 2, 2919
- 2, 2923
- 3, 2920

Summed Results:

- [Effective Date] guests fixedperiod revenuecenterid
- 2014-1-20, 200, 89, 146708

Expected Results:

- [Effective Date] guests fixedperiod revenuecenterid
- 2014-1-20, 10, 89, 146708

Comment: Why do you have distinct and group by? Could you show some sample data and desired results? I almost expect more rows than you do simply because of your overuse of distinct.

Comment: Distinct was merely carried over from my troubleshooting to identify the specific orders as without it they show up multiple times.  Group by is used due to the Sum.

Comment: Oh, please don't post a bunch of data in a comment. Either add sample data to the question or prepare it properly in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3).

Comment: The question has the data at the bottom.

Comment: Is that only data that matches the filters (e.g. falls on the openbusinessdate range in your where clause)? What are the summed results you *expect*?

Comment: That is the only Data that matches.  I'll put the expected results at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by identifying that all of the data I needed for the sum was in guest_check_hist and that the sum was somehow doubling the totals.

Answer (score 0):

Did  you try putting the filter in brackets in order to avoid confusion.

I think the "and fixedperiod = '89'" is causing more record. Put this statement above.

Comment: The fixed period reduces the number of records.  The system has 96 fixed periods per day in 15 minute increments.  To reduce the amount of data I had to explain I picked a specific period that was small enough to use.  Many other have 50 guests on 70+ orders.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made your query a heck of a lot more complex than it needs to be. Try this to start:

```
DECLARE @date DATE = '2014-01-20';

SELECT 
  [Effective Date] = m.businessdate, 
  guests = SUM(h.numguests), 
  h.fixedperiod, 
  h.revenuecenterid
FROM 
  dbo.MENU_ITEM_FIXED_PERIOD_TOTAL AS m
INNER JOIN dbo.guest_check_hist AS h
  ON h.openbusinessdate >= m.businessdate
  AND h.openbusinessdate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, m.businessdate)
  AND h.fixedperiod = m.fixedperiod
  AND h.revenuecenterid = m.revenuecenterid
WHERE m.businessdate = @date
GROUP BY m.businessdate, h.fixedperiod, h.revenuecenterid
ORDER BY h.fixedperiod;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9af30/2)

Comment: It's cleaner, but I get the exact same results.

Comment: @user3220005 Then you need to show better data. [Adjust the fiddle I created](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9af30/2) so that the tables there have the data that demonstrates the problem. I can't fix query results that are different than the ones you get using the only data I can see, when your data is obviously different than what you posted in the question.